# bazel test after build still takes very long

Tags: bazel

I ran the following commands

```
bazel test ...
bazel build ...
bazel test ...
```

It appears that the seconds test run did not take advantage of caching at all. What could be the reason?

Comment: Please provide a way to reproduce this. The second and third commands should be no-op after the first `bazel test ...`.

Comment: @Jin: sorry this is proprietary. Is it possible that if test rules only cover a small fraction of the build rules, that the second command would not be a no-op?

Comment: Unless you're using `--build_tests_only`, `bazel test ...` is essentially `bazel build ... && bazel test ...`. So the first command should build everything that the second and third commands require. What do you mean by "did not take advantage of caching"?

Comment: @Jin Thanks for clarifying! What happened is that only one out of many test failed, but when I rerun bazel test ... or bazel build ... it appears that bazel had to rerun almost half of the compiling work (as opposed to no actions).

Comment: Are you using stamping in your build? Try a build with `--nostamp`. Also try the flag `--keep_going`.

Comment: @Jin thanks for the tips! Will give them a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200573/discussion-between-john-jiang-and-jin).